# Gatling request body as bytearray

Tags: scala, gatling, scala-gatling, gatling-plugin

```
val scn = scenario("gatling test").
    feed(circularfeeder.circular)
    .exec(http("request")
      .post(endpoint)
      .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
      .header("Accept-Encoding", "charset=UTF-8")
      .body(StringBody("""${request}"""))
      .check(status.is(200))
```

The above code is used to send every circularfeeder data as a string to the body of the request. Suppose if i want to send as byte array instead of string in the body how do I modify the line `.body(StringBody("""${request}"""))`

The code `.body(ByteArrayBody(getBytesData("""${request}""")))` does not work. Any advise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**

Call `getBytes` method on `request` string and pass that to `ByteArrayBody`

```scala
.body(ByteArrayBody { session => 
  session("request")
    .validate[String]
    .map(s => s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) 
})
```

**Option 2**

Convert the raw data you got from your feeder.

```scala
val circularfeeder = csv("myFile.csv").convert {
  case ("request", string) => string.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
}
...
.body(ByteArrayBody("${request}"))
```